# Obtain leftmost cell and rightmost cell in a range that do not contain an error

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to obtain the address of the:

- leftmost cell in range A3:J3
- rightmost cell in range A3:J3

that do not contain an error, and then divide the second by the first.

Basically I want to see the revenues growth in the most large time frame available for each line.

[image: Table example]

I have no idea on how to approach the problem except using a veeery long series of `if(iserror(A1)=true;if(iserror(B2)=true;.....` but doesn't seem very productive.

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected the ranges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Office 365 we can use TAKE() and TOROW() to return the correct numbers.

TOROW() has the ability to ignore the errors and TAKE can take the first and last of what TOROW() returns:

```
=TAKE(TOROW(C3:J3;3);;-1)/TAKE(TOROW(C3:J3;3);;1)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very elegant solution! Many thanks!